# How to inherit metadata from two hierarchy levels?

Tags: document, metadata, sub-site, inheritance

Please excuse the confusing title - I wasn't sure how to articulate this problem. This image should help explain things:
[image: Image1]

So I have a Site Collection with a list of Products. In a sub-site is a list of Parts which are related to different products using Lookup. It pulls info from the parent table (Product:Priority). In the sub-site, I want to create documents associated with individual Parts, inheriting the metadata from both the Parts list and the Products list.

Ideally the user would upload a document and choose which part it relates to (from a single Lookup field). The other Part information (ID) and Product information would be added to the document's metadata automatically. Is this possible with OOTB sharepoint 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: Using OOTB Sharepoint you cannot create lookups to other (sub)sites.

Comment: It's the parent site, not another sub-site, that the second level info is pulled from. Does that help at all?

Comment: The same applies. Maybe the answer is in a termstore using managed metadata: create a termstore for storing the product names. Then you can use those product names in the three sites.